# How to use dynamic port in server.js as a source in index.html?

Tags: html, node.js, heroku

I am deploying to Heroku as a web app and not locally.

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}!`) //3000
})
```

I thought this was a workaround.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Photo stream sample</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <p id="serversource"></p>
      <!--<source src="http://localhost:19569/photo" type="photo/jpg">-->
  </body>
      <script>

   const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    var x = document.createElement("SOURCE");
  x.setAttribute("src", "http://localhost:80/photo"); //${PORT}
  x.setAttribute("type", "photo/jpg");
  document.getElementById("serversource").appendChild(x);

</script>
</html>
```

I also tried `http://___APP___NAME___.herokuapp.com:${PORT}/photo` instead of `http://localhost:80/photo`

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: You cannot access `process.env.PORT ` inside of your web page.  That is something that is ONLY available in your node.js code, not something you can use inside a web page.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use port and local host for index.html since you are not deploying locally and use `src` as the tag not `p`.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Photo stream sample</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <source id="serversource">
  </body>
      <script>
document.getElementById("serversource").src = "http://___APP___NAME___.herokuapp.com/photo"; document.getElementById("serversource").type = "photo/jpg";

</script>
</html>
```